# Second Child element of div should remain constant

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs inside one parent div. Please see the image so It will have a better idea. [Also including the jsfiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/ramdeo_angh/m2pLghqe/1/)

```css
#parent{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:150px;
  width:250px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  text-align:center;    
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:12px;
  margin-top:10px; 
}

#container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:12px; 
} 

.fnt{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
<div id="container">
  <div class='fnt'>500</div>
  <div>/</div>
  <div>20</div>
</div>

<div id="container1">
  <div class='fnt'>My Task</div>
  <div>/</div>
  <div>total task</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
#parent{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:150px;
  width:250px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  text-align:center;    
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:12px;
  margin-top:10px; 
}

#container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:12px; 
} 

.fnt{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
<div id="container">
  <div class='fnt'>500</div>
  <div>/</div>
  <div>20</div>
</div>

<div id="container1">
  <div class='fnt'>My Task</div>
  <div>/</div>
  <div>total task</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the output of the above piece of code.

[image: OUTPUT IMAGE]

My expected output is in this image. Here my only concern is If I increase the value of **my task** , It should not change the position of slash ("/" ). It must be aligned with the second-row text.

[image: My expected output is in this image. Here my only concern is If I increase the value of my task , It should not change the position of slash ("/" ). It must be aligned with the second-row text. also have a glance on font.]

Comment: Did you post two identical snippets?

Comment: Move `/ total task` inside a `span` and place it inside the `.fnt` and then give it separate css rules.

Comment: Do you need such a result? - https://ibb.co/s6hB6Qm

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Yes the perfect one.but there is one problem. look at the slash. both are not aligned. both slash position should not be changed

Comment: @pistevw here In seperate css, Can I put line-height:unset !important? And what about the "SLASH" alignment.

Comment: @ram, if you add `flex: 1` for internal div, except for the central one, then you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make the width consistent, you can use grid, like this

```css
#parent{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:150px;
  width:250px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  text-align:center;    
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:12px;
  margin-top:10px; 
}

#container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:12px; 
} 

.fnt{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2.4rem;
    text-align: right; /* the left side is aligned right */
}
#parent > div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 10px 100px; /* separate into 3 parts, the middle is the slash, so it just need small width */
  grid-gap: 5px; /* distance between grids */
}
/* this is styling other than .fnt, change this as you want for the slash and right side */
#parent > div > div:not(.fnt) { 
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.4rem;
}
#parent > div > div:last-child{
  text-align: left; /* the right side is aligned left */
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
<div id="container">
  <div class='fnt'>500</div>
  <div>/</div>
  <div>20</div>
</div>

<div id="container1">
  <div class='fnt'>My Task</div>
  <div>/</div>
  <div>total task</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use display **flex**, you can do that too , but personally i prefer the grid approach because you don't have to set the individual width, all set in `grid-template-columns`

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:12px;
  margin-top:10px; 
}

#container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:12px; 
} 

.fnt{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2.4rem;
    text-align: right; /* the left side is aligned right */
}
#parent > div {
  display: flex; /* change grid to flex */
  justify-content: flex-start; 
  flex-direction: row; /* actually you don't have to set this, because the default value of flex-direction is 'row' */
}
#parent > div > div {
  width: 100px /* set width for div inside .container */
}
#parent > div > div:nth-child(2n) {
  width: 10px; /* set slash width */
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#parent > div > div:not(.fnt) { 
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.4rem;
}
#parent > div > div:last-child{
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Can we achieve it using flex and flex-direction:row

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply. yes you can do that with flex, too! i have edit the answer